# Unable to load finetune_checkpoint in object detection training

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md).

I am using Oxford-IIIT Pet data and config file similar to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config).

In the pipeline_config file, I have specified fine tune check point as

```
fine_tune_checkpoint: "{PATH TO}/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt"
from_detection_checkpoint: false
```

But when I run,
python object_detection/train.py ... --train_dir=${PATH_TO_TRAIN_DIR}

I am getting a list of warnings.

**WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint.**

.

.

.

**WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV1/Conv2d_9_pointwise/weights] not available in checkpoint**

and program exits saying

**ValueError: No variables to save**

I have inspected the ckpt in python using

```
print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file('{PATH TO}/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt/model.ckpt', '',"")
```

The output was a list.

**FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/BatchNorm/beta (DT_FLOAT) [32]**

.

.

.

**FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_9_pointwise/weights (DT_FLOAT) [1,1,512,512]**

**Note**:Training script runs fine when finetune_checkpoint is disabled by

```
from_detection_checkpoint: true
```

in pipeline config file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `from_detection_checkpoint: true` is actually required for the checkpoint file that you are using because that model was trained as a detector (so nothing is being disabled).

You would only set `from_detection_checkpoint: false` if you wanted to train starting from one of the [Slim models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim) that was pre-trained for Imagenet classification.